# Trying to print smallest of 4 integers - MIPS

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

I am taking 4 integer inputs from the user and trying to print the smallest one of them. But my loop does not seem to work properly. Please help me out.

```
      .text
      .globl main
main:  addi $v0, $0, 5
       syscall
       add $t0, $0, $v0

       addi $v0, $0, 5
       syscall
       add $t1, $0, $v0

       addi $v0, $0, 5
       syscall
       add $t2, $0, $v0

       addi $v0, $0, 5
       syscall
       add $t3, $0, $v0

       addi $a1, $0, $0

loop:  sltu $a2, $t0, $t1
       beq  $a2, $0, L1

L1:    addi $a2, $0, $t0
       addi $a1, $a1, 1
       j loop

       addi $v0, $0, 1
       add $a0, $0, $a2
```

Comment: Did my answer was correct? If so, please mark it as correct! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure, but if `beq $a2, $0, L1` doesn't jump to `L1`, it just continues and still execute the code under `L1`.

Try adding a jump under the `beq` to jump at the end of the program.